# ¿Nombre del pájaro que contiene las letras 'ü' y 'ñ'?

Tags: animales

Fui al zoo el otro día, y vi un pájaro con un nombre muy raro. Pero ya no lo recuerdo. Si sé que su nombre contiene las letras 'ü' y 'ñ'. ¿Alguien aquí sabe cuál es esta palabra?

Gracias.

Answer (score 6):

### Ñandú

> El Ñandú es un ave no voladora y exclusivamente sudamericana. Sus patas, que terminan en tres dedos, son fuertes y están adaptadas para la carrera. El plumaje es de color marrón grisáceo; al igual que las avestruces, tiene el cuello largo, la cabeza pequeña y un pico más bien fuerte. Pertenecen al sur de América.
> El ñandú es incapaz de volar, sin embargo todo su cuerpo está adaptado para correr a gran velocidad si se ve en peligro, es torpe para saltar pero es un buen nadador si necesita cruzar algún curso de agua.

### Cigüeña

> La Cigüeña Blanca es un ave migratoria que anuncia el buen tiempo con su llegada (alrededor del mes de febrero).
> Muy similar a la Cigüeña Americana (llamada igualmente “Cigüeña Blanca” o “Cigüeña Común”), es conocida como “White Stork” en inglés, y no se caracteriza por ser de las más grandes de su especie (tampoco la más pequeña).

<sub>*Via [zoomadrid.com](https://www.zoomadrid.com/animales-y-continentes/animales/nandu)*</sub>

### Cigüeñuela

> La cigüeñuela es una pequeña ave acuática que se caracteriza por sus larguísimas patas en relación con el tamaño del cuerpo. Su pico, estrecho y largo, le permite capturar entre el barro los pequeños invertebrados de los que se alimenta.

<sub>*Via [zoobarcelona.cat](https://www.zoobarcelona.cat/es/animales/ciguenuela)*</sub>